# Bottom of my page won't respond to an CSS styling

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with this layout. Everything went smooth up until I got past the "section banner". Nothing will respond to CSS correctly. I can't align anything. I got the "col-md-4" to center correctly, but the header above it will not move where i want it. The only way I can get it to center is to put it in between the "row" div. But that doesnt solve the face that I can't adjust the padding/margin for it at all.

Also the footer is completely out of wack. Can't get it to center. Nothing.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.header {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* Header */

.nav {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}
.nav-pills li a {
  color: #d8192f;
}
.nav-pills li.active a,
.nav-pills li a:hover,
.section .btn:hover {
  background-color: rgba(216, 25, 47, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  color: #fff;
}
.row-centered {
  text-align: center;
}
.col-centered {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  /* reset the text-align */
  text-align: left;
  /* inline-block space fix */
  margin-right: -4px;
}
/* Jumbotron */

.jumbotron {
  height: 500px;
  background: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/bestbite/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.jumbotron h2:first-child {
  margin: 100px 0 0;
}
.jumbotron h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
}
/* Banner */

.banner,
.supporting {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.banner {
  background-color: #36343f;
  height: 150px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.btn {
  background-color: rgba(216, 25, 47, .5);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
}
/* Media Queries */

@media (max-width: 680px) {
  .header h1 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .header2 h2 {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
  }
  .footer {
    max-width: 33%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    clear: both;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row row-centered">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-centered">
          <h1>BestBite</h1> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-centered">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Log In</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Browse.</h2>
        <h2>Create.</h2>
        <h2>Share.</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section banner">
    <div class="container">
      <h3>Always have the answer to "What's for dinner?"</h3>
      <a class="btn" href="#">Learn More</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header2">
        <h2>Test</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="row row-centered">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h3>One</h3>
          <p>One</p>
          <p>Two</p>
          <p>Three</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h3>Two</h3>
          <p>One</p>
          <p>Two</p>
          <p>Three</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h3>Three</h3>
          <p>One</p>
          <p>Two</p>
          <p>Three</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p class="a-left">One</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p class="a-center">One</p>
        <div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <p class="a-right">One</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What's the correct behavior you are expecting to accomplish?

Comment: Not sure if this is part of the problem, but you have a typo in one of the closing divs in your footer. `<div class="col-md-4"><p class="a-center">One</p><div>` You end with an opening div.

Comment: Im just trying to center everything and give the header bottom padding/margin. Im going to try fixing that now to see if it helps. Thanks.

Comment: That actually helped a lot. I still can't adjust the margin/padding for this

   <div class="header2"><h2>Test</h2></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have on extra `}` at your css (before the media queries).

Also, you had to set a div block with 100% width to center your footer, and add `text-align: center` to the child p tags.

For footer margin on large screen, just add:

```
.row .footer{
   margin: 30px 0
}
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1pwbhuzz/3/

Comment: dude.....thank you so much, That was it!

Comment: one more problem. when i adjust the padding for the footer, it looks good on a small screen, but on a large screen there is no margin/padding

Comment: You probably just have to add margin to the p elements of the footer instead of the footer itself. I'll take a look at it once a get to my pc.

Comment: Check the change I made pls.

Answer (score 0):

With this you'll have the footer columns centered:

**HTML**

```
 <div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4"><p>One</p></div>
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4"><p>One</p></div>
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4"><p>One</p></div>
     </div></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.footer p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

And delete the footer class in your media query.

Comment: idk why but that made things worse, i have everything centered now, but can't adjust padding/margin

Comment: padding/margin for what elements?